# How to keep RecyclerView displayed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, dialog

I created a RecyclerView within dialogfragment. I have set recyclerView's `Visibility = GONE` in the dialogfragment's xml.  When I search in the searchview, RecyclerView is set to `Visibility.VISIBLE` and display data. But When I open the dialogfragment that was searched and `dismiss()` before opening, recycleview's Visibility become GONE again. Those data might have gone.
 How to make the recyclerview maintain the previous display-state and data?

Comment: dialogfragment isn't  a new dialogfragment

Comment: Who else can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to preserve the state of dialog fragment if you wants to preserve recyclerview state, Do not call dismiss() you can use hide();

Comment: I can't either find dialogfragment or recyclerview have hide() method

Answer (score 0):

if only RecyclerView inside dialog then no need to set Visibility only notify adapter every time to call api and fill data, hope help you.

Comment: In my app's activity has a botton , i need click it then show recycleview and data within it  , if adapter has data .  Fill data  isn't work , i had try it .

Comment: At the beginning, the recycleview has no data. After the query, the data is given to the recycleview.

Comment: Implement onitemclick and dialogfragment dismiss . I need the RecyclerView Keep state and data present when i click the botton show dialog again .  But i still be gone with data